# How to use mapstruct on the parent object to detect the right child mapper?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Does mapstruct allow to detect the right child mapper from the parent object?

We have multiple class that extends a parent class and we want a way to find the right mapper automaticly.

The solution I though of involve a map of mapper class and load the right one when you check the object class or type.
Another solution is to have a convoluted switch case or if else with a instance of each possible child class.

Example of the model:

```
public class ParentClass{
String getType();
}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

}

public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
}
```

to this dto model:

```
public class ParentClassDto{
String getType();
}

public class ChildClass1Dto extends ParentClassDto{

}

public class ChildClass2Dto extends ParentClassDto {
}
```

Everything work fine when it's one for one (ChildClass1 -> ChildClass1Dto with ChildClass1Mapper or ChildClass2 -> ChildClass2Dto with ChildClass2Mapper)

Our current solution involve a map with the mapper like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface ParentClassMapper{
    ParentClassDto convertToDto(ParentClass p);
    ParentClass convertDTOToModel(ParentClassDto dto);
}


@Mapper
public interface ChildClass1Mapper implements ParentClassMapper
```

The map to find the right one :

```
public class MapperFinder{

    static Map<String, ParentClassMapper> map;

    static {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("ParentClassType", ParentClassMapper.class);
        map.put("ChildClass1Type", ChildClass1Mapper.class);
        map.put("ChildClass2Type", ChildClass2Mapper.class);
    }

    public ParentClassDto mapModelToDTO(ParentClass p){
        Class mapperClass = map.get(p.getType);
        MyMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper( mapperClass );
        return mapper.convertToDto(p);
    }


    public ParentClass mapDTOToModel(ParentClassDto dto){
        Class mapperClass = map.get(dto.getType);
        MyMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper( mapperClass );
        return mapper.convertDTOToModel(dto);
    }
}
```

and the usage would be in the service

```
@Autowired
MapperFinder mapperFinder;

public void save (ParentClass pc){
    (pc is a instance of child ChildClass1)
    ... 
    ParentClassDto dto = mapperFinder.mapModelToDTO(pc);
    repo.save(dto);
    ...
}
```

Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: The question was indirectly fix via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444711/mapping-element-of-a-list-of-different-type-with-mapstruct

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/pull/62) example (still a PR) on the examples repo. It proposes a standard mapper interface and a repository function to (more-or-less) achieve what you want.