# Mapping element of a list of different type with mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

We are mapping a object that have a list of object that all implement a parent interface but may have a different implementation. 
But it seem when we are mapping the list only the value from ParentClass was mapped not the value from the child.
But mapping directly the child workfine.

```
public class ParentClass{
String name;
int anotherParentField;
List<ParentClass> relation;
}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{
String customCLass1Field;
}

public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
int intField;
}


public class ParentClassDto{
String name;
int anotherParentField;
List<ParentClassDto> relation;
}

public class ChildClass1Dto extends ParentClassDto{
String customCLass1Field;
}

public class ChildClass2Dto extends ParentClassDto {
int intField;
}
```

The mappers

```
@Mapper
public interface ParentClassMapper{
    ParentClassDto convertToDto(ParentClass p);
    ParentClass convertDTOToModel(ParentClassDto dto);
}


@Mapper
public interface ChildClass1Mapper implements ParentClassMapper
{
    ChildClass1Dto convertToDto(ChildClass1 p);
    ChildClass1 convertDTOToModel(ChildClass1Dto dto);
}

@Mapper
public interface ChildClass2Mapper implements ParentClassMapper
{
    ChildClass2Dto convertToDto(ChildClass2 p);
    ChildClass2 convertDTOToModel(ChildClass2Dto dto);
}
```

When with this if we map a object ChildClass1 containing ChildClass2 and ChildClass1 in a list we get.

object to map: 
the object ChildClass1 would look like this in json format:

```
{
   "name":"myName",
   "anotherParentField":"10",
   "customCLass1Field":"custom name",
   "relation":[
      {
         (This is of Object Type : ChildClass1)
         "name":"firstRelationName",
         "anotherParentField":"110",
         "customCLass1Field":"relationcustom name"
      },
      {
         (This is of Object Type : ChildClass2)
         "name":"secondRelationName",
         "anotherParentField":"110",
         "intField":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

But when we use the mapper above to map to dto we get:

```
{
   "name":"myName",
   "anotherParentField":"10",
   "customCLass1Field":"custom name",
   "relation":[
      {
         "name":"firstRelationName",
         "anotherParentField":"110",
      },
      {
         "name":"secondRelationName",
         "anotherParentField":"110",
      }
   ]
}
```

None of the field from the child class are mapped. 
What's missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see another way than have a custom mapper.

Here is my solution with what they call [decorator](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators):

```
public abstract class ParentClassMapperDecorator implements ParentClassMapper {

  private final ParentClassMapper delegate;

  public ParentClassMapperDecorator(ParentClassMapper delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public ParentClass convertDTOToModel(ParentClassDto dto) {
    ParentClass parentClass = null;

    if (dto instanceof ChildClass1Dto) {
      parentClass = Mappers.getMapper(ChildClass1Mapper.class).convertDTOToModel((ChildClass1Dto) dto);
    } else if (dto instanceof ChildClass2Dto) {
      parentClass = Mappers.getMapper(ChildClass2Mapper.class).convertDTOToModel((ChildClass2Dto) dto);
    } else {
      parentClass = this.delegate.convertDTOToModel(dto);
    }

    return parentClass;
  }

  @Override
  public ParentClassDto convertToDto(ParentClass p) {
    // Do the job here
  }
}
```

And in ParentClassMapper add the @DecoratedWith annotation:

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(ParentClassMapperDecorator.class)
public interface ParentClassMapper {

  ParentClassDto convertToDto(ParentClass p);

  ParentClass convertDTOToModel(ParentClassDto dto);
}
```

For the child:

```
@Mapper(uses = {ParentClassMapper.class})
public interface ChildClass1Mapper{

  ChildClass1Dto convertToDto(ChildClass1 p);

  ChildClass1 convertDTOToModel(ChildClass1Dto dto);
}

@Mapper(uses = {ParentClassMapper.class})
public interface ChildClass2Mapper {

  ChildClass2Dto convertToDto(ChildClass2 p);

  ChildClass2 convertDTOToModel(ChildClass2Dto dto);
}
```

If you want to test:

```
@Test
  public void mapStruct_Inheritance_Test() throws Exception {

    ChildClass1Dto childClass1Dto = new ChildClass1Dto();
    childClass1Dto.name = "name1";
    childClass1Dto.anotherParentField = 1;
    childClass1Dto.customCLass1Field = "customCLass1Field1";

    List<ParentClassDto> parentClassDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    ChildClass1Dto childClass11Dto = new ChildClass1Dto();
    childClass11Dto.name = "name12";
    childClass11Dto.anotherParentField = 12;
    childClass11Dto.customCLass1Field = "customCLass1Field12";
    parentClassDtos.add(childClass11Dto);

    ChildClass2Dto childClass21Dto = new ChildClass2Dto();
    childClass21Dto.name = "name12";
    childClass21Dto.anotherParentField = 21;
    childClass21Dto.intField = 210;
    parentClassDtos.add(childClass21Dto);

    childClass1Dto.relation = parentClassDtos;

    ParentClass parentClass = Mappers.getMapper(ParentClassMapper.class).convertDTOToModel(childClass1Dto);
  }
```

Comment: To be honest I don't think you need to reference the `ParentMapper` in the children. That mapper is not going to be used in the children